# Sendmail entry in /etc/aliases that modifies the email header before sending it out?

Tags: sed, scripting, sendmail

I'm using Sendmail I want to create an alias in /etc/aliases, that modifies the To: line before sending out the message . I assume I need some sort of script or command that the email is piped into. Any suggestions?

A very basic modification is needed. I need to change an address from foo@foobar to foo@barfoo. Thanks!

Comment: Mail aliases don't do that. Read `man sendmail`. Most `sendmail`s will let you specify the `from:` name and address.

Comment: There is a difference between changing the `To:` header line in the mail
that goes out, and keeping it unchanged but sending the mail to a new
address derived from it. The former is difficult and needs a
[milter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milter), the latter is easily done
by using a [virtusertable](https://etutorials.org/Server+Administration/Sendmail/Part+I+Build+and+Install/Chapter+4.+Configure+sendmail.cf+with+m4/FEATUREvirtusertable/). Aliases can change user `foo` to `foo@barfoo`, but not from `foo@foobar`.